# error with docker-compose and django

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to get started with docker and django. I followed the directions of docker-compose and created an image with a simple requirements.txt.

I now want to actually build out my app more and add templates and actual code.

1) i installed some modules on the host machine and added them to the requirements.txt file

2) i run (again) docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject exampleproject. All my new requirements get downloaded but then i get this error:

/code/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files

I am using the exact Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml as here:
http://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

how am i supposed to update the container/image with new templates/views &c and new modules as i am developing my app?

am i using docker wrong?

thanks.

Comment: have you removed the container before trying to run docker-compose again?

Comment: I needed to remove the manage.py from the directory where i had my project - i thought it would just update with new requirements but i think if i wanted to do that i would have to restart the project all over again. I guess once you start a project, you install new requirements on the container itself and add them to requirements.txt for the next time you build your project from scratch

Comment: following same tutorial:I am running docker insidew windows liux subsystem and 
this command `docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .` doesn't create something in the same folder 1st time. 2nd time I get this `CommandError: /code/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove the manage.py from the directory where i had my project (the directory where the docker-compose.yml is in).

I guess once you start a project, you install new requirements on the container itself and add them to requirements.txt for the next time you build your project from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late addition but I thought it might help someone. I had also encountered this same problem and inspite of removing manage.py from the folder where my .yml and Dockerfile existed, it gave me same error.

I have no idea where it made the code directory which had the manage.py file. But I worked around it presently by changing the service name in the yml file and restarting the project with the new service name.

```
docker-compose run newservicenm django-admin.py startproject projectname directoryname
```

This worked as a new container!